operator overloading for string concatenation c#.net
I have my custom data type as
public class AppIdentiy
{
    public string ID { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator AppIdentiy(string userID)
    {
        var result = new AppIdentiy()
        {
            ID = userID
        };
        return result;
    }

    public static implicit operator string(AppIdentiy identity)
    {
        if (identity is null)
            return string.Empty;
        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(identity.ID))
            return string.Empty;

        return identity.ID;
    }

    //public static string operator +(AppIdentiy a) => a.ID;

}

I am using this AppIdentiy like this for example
AppIdentiy myIdentity  = "nkg@xyz.com";

string email = myIdentity; //setting the variable email with the value 'nkg@xyz.com'

string comment  = "this is user email address '" + myIdentity + "' generated by xyz app"; //this is not working, I am expecting here when I use '+' operator with my datatype its value should populate here like 


"this is user email address 'nkg@xyz.com'  generated by xyz app"

I am not getting how to decorate the + operator overloading in my AppIdentiy class

You can simplify your implicit operator to: public static implicit operator string(AppIdentiy identity) => identity?.ID ?? String.Empty; (this does exactly the same as yours.)

"AppIdentiy" - is that a typo? Should that be "AppIdentity" ?

The + operator takes two operands - the left and right values (at least one of which must be of the declaring type); hence you could have any-or-all-of:
public static string operator +(AppIdentiy x, string y) => ...;
public static string operator +(string x, AppIdentiy y) => ...;
public static string operator +(AppIdentiy x, AppIdentiy y) => ...;

However, it seems unlikely that this is actually what you want to do here! You shouldn't usually need to override how string addition works, and it already works as I would expect for your type.

Your problem has nothing to with operator overloading. In a string concatenation operation such as "this is user email address '" + myIdentity the compiler automatically invokes the ToString() method on any item in the concatenation that is not already a string. Thus this will call AppIdentity.ToString() which, as it is not overriden, will return the default implementation, which returns the type name instead. To get the desired result, add the following to your AppIdentity class:
   public override string ToString()
   {
       return ID;
   }


In the OP's example, the implicit conversion to string already takes place, so ToString() is never called anyway.
